# Segmentation faults in DAG Program

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct da 
{
int ptr,left,right;
char label;
}dag[25];

int ptr,l,j,change,n=0,i=0,state=1,x,y,k;

char store,*input1,input[25],var;

l=strlen(input1); //i'm Getting Segmentaion Fault here
```

The Complete Program is here
http://bmohanrajcse.blogspot.com/2018/01/9-construction-of-dag.html

I didn't Know where & what to correct ,Please help

Comment: The string `input1` is not initialized, so reading it to determine how long it is will likely go outside allocated memory, which is causing the segmentation fault that you see.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is uninitialized. `strlen(NULL)` will segfault.  Try this:

```
char *input = "";
```